# How do I install indicator-weather in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: 14.10, applet, weather

I want to install `indicator-weather` in ubuntu 14.10, since to me is the best aproach to a weather applet, but it's not on repositories and even if you add the ppa, there is no utopic version.

1. How do I install it?
2. What similar alternatives exist if I can't install it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also a big fan of `indicator-weather` that I replaced by `my-weather-indicator` since no new versions are available as of 14.04.

`my-weather-indicator` is also a small indicator (as `indicator-weather` was):

[image]

You can install `my-weather-indicator` from the following ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator python3-requests
```

Comment: `my-weather-indicator` is installed under `/opt` and dash cannot find it. how do I start it?